# db class select not outputting as expected

Tags: php, class

I am trying to output a value from the db when using the class as demonstrated at the bottom of the following code.

But this is not outputting the value as expected.

i am terribly new to classes and just cannot see where i am wrong here

```
$getx = new getx();

class getx extends hush { 
    public function username($uidr) {
       global $dbx;

       $usernameR = $dbx->qry(" SELECT username FROM exp_members WHERE member_id = '$uidr' ");

       $row = mysql_fetch_array($usernameR, MYSQL_ASSOC);

       return $usernamex = $row['username'];

    }
    public function email($uidr) {  
       global $dbx;

       $emailR = $dbx->qry(" SELECT email FROM exp_members WHERE member_id = '$uidr' ");

       $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($emailR, MYSQL_ASSOC);

       return $email = $row2['email'];

    }

} 

echo $username = $getx->username(1); // this is not working as expected
```

Error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function qry() on a non-object in..`

@ this point `$usernameR = $dbx->qry(" SELECT username FROM exp_members WHERE member_id = '$uidr' ");`

the part that handles the db

```
//database x credentials
$dbx = new queryx("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");

class queryx extends hush { //queryx is the query port for the cms 
    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$dbname) {
        mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)
            or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db($dbname)
            or die(mysql_error());
    }
    public function qry($sql) {
       // return mysql_query($sql);
            $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            return $query;  
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of errors?! Uf so, please provide them here. Also, I would suggest not to use the mysql extention, but to use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: yes, updated question with the error @RobinR

Comment: A qry function doesn't exist. Try to use the basic mysql_query instead.

Comment: @RobinR Updated with the function it does exist!

Comment: Try calling your class right before you try to get your data.

Comment: Does the file containing the `getx` class include the file containing the `queryx` class? It does not appear so, and the line `$dbx = new queryx("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");` is not executed before you attempt to use `$getx = new getx();`

Comment: the only thing outside of the class file is the `$getx->username(1)` 
the class file is `require_once` at the top of the file.